# Series, girl from a village with a bell, escaped with chubby friend who becomes a wrestler

Tags: story-identification, novel, prophecy

I remember reading a trilogy (or maybe there were 4 books) in the early 2000s.

The protagonist was a young girl who lived in a small village and there was a large tower, possibly with a bell. I think her mother was a prophet but I remember that the mother died. There was conflict or war in the village, and the girl escaped with other people include a male friend of hers who was quite chubby/fat and wore dark round glasses.

What I remember about this friend was that in one of the later books he became a wrestler of sorts, and ended up dying after being stabbed during one of the matches.

It's been so long, but I remember it was a great series of books that I'd like to get back to reading.

Both mother and daughter do a lot of prophesying during the books. In the original village, the bell in the tower is used to alert of a conflict/attack. Maybe in the third book, they get trapped in a fantasy land/swamp where they float around, eat great food.

They go to a new land and are enslaved, or trapped. The boy became a great wrestler, and never loses. He realizes he is about to lose a match and stabs himself rather than lose. The land where they are, everyone is enslaved (including the second in command), and the king would do weird things like urinate in the middle of the room to show his ultimate control.